# Python: For loop skip in If

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop, skip

Why do the line "old_langpacks.append(act_item)" get skipped?
When I use just the for loop, without the if, then it works.

```
    if act_file == "Languages.csv":
        temp_list = open(act_file,"r")
        for act_item in temp_list:
            old_langpacks.append(act_item)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Err... maybe because act_file isn't "Languages.csv"? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: It looks as if the condition is not true. For easy debugging, at print statements to both branches so you can see which is taken.

Comment: print act_file, "Languages.csv" to check if they are really same.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is not working is because your if condition is evaluating to false.

In addition to what Mark Byers suggested one thought came to mind:

Is it possible that `act_file` is a file object, opposed to a string which represents the name of the file?

How is act_file created?

If you obtain it via something similar to:

```
act_file = open("Languages.csv")
```

then you will not be able to check its name the way you have written, because act_file is indeed a file object.

If act_file is a file object, the correct way to write your if statement would be:

```
if act_file.name == "Languages.csv":
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the condition in your `if` is resulting in `False` even though you think it *should* be `true`.

That might be due to case sensitivity - if you are on Windows, the file names will work with any casing, but the string comparison in your `if` won't compare true, if the case of any letter in the `act_file` variable differs from the way they are in the `Languages.csv` string.

To work around this I'd suggest you change the `if` line to:

```
if act_file.lower() == "languages.csv":
```